# Get all site product ID in magento

Tags: magento

Now, i want to get all product ID of my site. IS there a simple way to get all  product ID in my site of magento,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection() as $product)
{
    var_dump($product->getId());
}
```

Comment: Yes, I do know the meaning of Mage::app('default');

Comment: It initializes the store application object (Mage_Core_Model_App) with the store code "default" and returns that same object.  If an application object has already been initialized, it simply returns the application object.

Comment: this solution is very very resource expensive. This way, you hydrate all the product in your catalog just to get only ids. And with foreach you double the memory consumption. I know it's an informative answer, not a solution, but maybe worth to be explicit about this, no?

Answer (score 6):

To save resources it is better to use:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->getAllIds();
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you have access to command line, run `mysql -u your_username -p magento_database` and then you can run this query:
`SELECT entity_id, sku FROM catalog_product_entity;` don't forget that you might need something like `LIMIT 0,30` or `WHERE sku LIKE '%shirt%'`. You can get to this via the command line or from phpmyadmin (if available). phpmyadmin has a query window in it somewhere.

I normally do sneaky things in Magento by creating php scripts in the `var/export/` folder. Then you do not need to worry about how to interact with the Magento/Zend/MVC framework.

Answer (score 0):

little variation If you All Product id from particular categories then:

```
    $category_ids = array(11,16); // your category ids
            $productIds = array();

            foreach($category_ids as $category_id){
                $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
                $result = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addCategoryFilter($category)->getAllIds();
                $productIds = array_merge($productIds,$result);
            }
var_dump($productIds);
```